# How can I modify this code to search 60000 rows and paste 1700 found values in adjacent column

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to excel Visual Basic Macro programming, attempting to create a find/copy/paste macro that will search for "$" in Column A (which has 60000 rows (with intermittent blanks)).  I have been able to discover that there are 1700 occurrences of "$" in column A that I must paste into the adjacent column B for each Cell in columnA where data is found.

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub FindAValue()
'
'This macro finds the value and paste to a single cell
'

'
Selection.Find(What:="$", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart
, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
Range("A2").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B2").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Application.CutCopyMode=False
End Sub
```

I have reviewed numerous postings from various blogs and am still unable to understand how to extend this macro so that it searches all of ColumnA, find each occurrence of "$", and paste it in ColumnB next to each line of ColumnA until a blank is found.  Each of the 1700 "$" values are unique and the number of subsequent cells also vary up to 60000 lines (which includes blanks.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It is unclear why you need VBA for this.  If you use the formula `=IFERROR(FIND("$",A1), "")` in column B (and replace `A1` with the first cell in your column A) and then copy that formula down the range, you'll see all the occurrences?

Comment: Cjrh:  Thanks for the response, I was told that using VBA macro is the easiest way to accomplish this task.  With that said, I tried your suggestion and did not receive the expected response.  I copied the code as shown and only changed the column reference to match my sheet and the actual result only displays a number one (1) in column b on the adjacent line that contains $ found in column A.  I need it to copy the contents of that cell to the adjacent cells of Column b.  I guess I could have made that part much clearer.

Comment: I meant to give you a basic idea of the formula.  Try this: `=IF(IFERROR(FIND("$",A1), 0)>0,A1,"")`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for something like this

```
Public Const DATACOL = 1
Public Const DESTCOL = 2

Sub exp()


'set initial row value
Row = 1
'iterate until a blank is found
Do While Cells(Row, DATACOL) <> ""
  'look is each datacell for $
  'instr returns the location of the search string as a number
  'and will return 0 if not found
  If InStr(1, Cells(Row, DATACOL), "$") > 0 Then
  'copy data
    Cells(Row, DESTCOL) = Cells(Row, DATACOL)
  End If

  'next row
  Row = Row + 1
Loop

End Sub
```